# Get rid of the "Broken" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Its basically the same as having a problem, issue, or other tag thats says they have a problem.

59 questions with it though, so its a little big for a manual de-tag (or not? not really sure).

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for burnination and blocking. I'll ask a dev if they can do that for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[broken](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/broken) is broken.

[image: tag burninated]